# error while adding custom option programatically on product save event in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I was trying to add the custom option programatically at the time of product save event.But when i tried it it is redirecting to a "Page not working" Page.

The code I tried on the observer is

```
<?php


namespace Custom\Addcustomoption\Observer\Catalog;

class ProductSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
     protected $ObjectManager;
     protected $product;

   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $ObjectManager,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
  ){

    $this->_objectManager = $ObjectManager;
    $this->_product = $product;

  }
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {

        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $productId = $_product->getId();
        $_products = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

        if(!$_products->getHasOptions()){


            try{

                $customOption = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');

                $customOptions = array();
                $customOption->setTitle('Text')
                ->setType('area')
                ->setIsRequire(true)
                ->setSortOrder(1)
                ->setPrice(1.00)
                ->setPriceType('fixed')                
                ->setProductSku($_products->getSku());
               //The code execute upto here
                $customOptions[] = $customOption;
                //problem is here
                $_products->setOptions($customOptions)->save();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());

            }

        }


    }
}
```

I tried to track it and the problem occurs at the time of setting the custom option to the product see the comment that i have placed on the code.

I didn't see any error on error log or apache log.

Can any one tell what could have possibly gone wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Put this - ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);   Below the namespace and check and post here what error it displays ?

Comment: @Manthan I had placed the code below namespace but it still isn't displaying any error

Comment: I tried placing it on controller but still no error just the page not working error page. The problem is with $_products->setOptions($customOptions)->save();

Comment: I tried putting it on index.php both on root and inside of pub dirrectory both but still no error.

Comment: @ManthanDave I have got the error message please see the above edit. can you help now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to figure out the solution to it. Thanks to @Manathan Dave for his valuable insights on the error reporting.

The actual problem was on the parameter set on the customOption object. I check the default custom option parameter passed while adding the custom option from admin panel and I modified my code according to that making the passed parameter same and it worked.

Below is my updated code:

```
<?php


namespace Custom\Addcustomoption\Observer\Catalog;

class ProductSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
     protected $ObjectManager;
     protected $product;

   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $ObjectManager,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
  ){

    $this->_objectManager = $ObjectManager;
    $this->_product = $product;

  }
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {

         $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
         $productId = $_product->getId();
        // $_products = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

         if(!$_product->getHasOptions()){


        try{            
                $customOption = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');

                $var = NULL;
                $customOption
                ->setOptionId($var)
                ->setProductId($productId)
                ->setType('field')
                ->setIsRequire("0")
                ->setSku("")
                ->setMaxCharacters("0") 
                ->setFileExtension("")
                ->setImageSizeX("0")
                ->setImageSizeY("0")
                ->setSortOrder("1")
                ->setDefaultTitle("Profile Name")
                ->setStoreTitle("Profile Name")
                ->setTitle("Profile Name")                
                ->setDefaultPrice("0.00")
                ->setDefaultPriceType("fixed") 
                ->setStorePrice("0.00")
                ->setStorePriceType("0.00")
                ->setPrice("0.00")
                ->setPriceType('fixed')                               
                ->setRecordId("0")                
                ->setProductSku($_product->getSku());               
                $customOptions[] = $customOption;                
                $_product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());

            }


         }


    }
}
```

This creates the custom option on the admin panel however, I am still facing the issue of it not appearing on the frontend but if I save the product than the option will be shown on frontend. So there is still an issue, but this answer is for creating custom option and it creates it.

> Update

On looking further I get the HasOptions() property on the product is not set to 1 so the custom option is not visible on frontend. Setting this to 1 will solve the problem but I am not able to set it.

I am working on my remaining issue if it gets fixed I will update the answer.

Comment: Did you ever get has_options to save?